# scrapy, selenium doesn't return all the element in the page

Tags: python, performance, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to reduce the time it takes the code to finish scraping the pages, I'm using selenium.
I used Scrapy for this scraping project, but JavaScript was hiding the email elements from Scrapy .

Scrapy was perfect, I don't know if there's a way to reduce the time in selenium or there's another way, or another tool or package to use in such a case?

If there's any information or docs to know more about it I would be thankful.

Here's the code:

```py
import scrapy
import logging

def decode_email_protection(encoded_string):
    if encoded_string:
        encoded_data = encoded_string.split('#')[-1]

        r = int(encoded_data[:2], 16)
        email = ''.join([chr(int(encoded_data[i:i + 2], 16) ^ r) for i in range(2, len(encoded_data), 2)])

        encoded_data = email.split('#')[-1]

        r = int(encoded_data[4:6], 16)
        encoded_data = encoded_data[:4] + encoded_data[6:]
        email = ''.join([chr(int(encoded_data[i:i + 2], 16) ^ r) for i in range(0, len(encoded_data), 2)])
        return email
    else:
        return None




class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["mdpi.com"]
    base_url = "https://www.mdpi.com/search?q=biomaterials"
    
    def start_requests(self):        
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url , callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        article_hrefs = response.xpath("//a[@class='title-link']/@href").getall()

        for href in article_hrefs:
            yield response.follow(url=href, callback=self.parse_page)

        next_page_link = response.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'pageSelect')]/a[6]/@href").get()
        if next_page_link:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_page(self, response):

        title = response.xpath("//h1[contains(@class,'title')]/text()").get(default="").strip()
        authors = response.xpath("//a[@class='profile-card-drop'][1]//text()").get(default="").strip()
        #authors = [i.strip() for i in authors]
        email_href = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'email')]/@href").get(default="")
        email = decode_email_protection(email_href)

        yield {
            "Title": title,
            "Link": response.url,
            "Authors": authors,
            "Email": email
        }
```

EDIT:
this's the new version of the code thanks for @SuperUser.
the problem now is the scrapy returns 15 articles per page and it should be 50 articles .
i used scrapy shell and i saw that the article_href method returns 15 link.
i tried and searched for a reason but got nothing .
even though i thought the problem was in the scrapy so i did use selenium with it, but still got the same problem, didn't get all the article in the page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email address is protected by CloudFlare's email protection script (it's actually double-encoded). I have found the decoding script online, but it was for single encoding string so I had to modify it.

Here's how you can scrape the website with Scrapy (no selenium):

**EDIT**: added dynamic pagination to get all the items on a single page.

```py
import scrapy
import logging


def decode_email_protection(encoded_string):
    encoded_data = encoded_string.split('#')[-1]

    r = int(encoded_data[:2], 16)
    email = ''.join([chr(int(encoded_data[i:i + 2], 16) ^ r) for i in range(2, len(encoded_data), 2)])

    encoded_data = email.split('#')[-1]

    r = int(encoded_data[4:6], 16)
    encoded_data = encoded_data[:4] + encoded_data[6:]
    email = ''.join([chr(int(encoded_data[i:i + 2], 16) ^ r) for i in range(0, len(encoded_data), 2)])
    return email


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["mdpi.com"]
    base_url = "https://www.mdpi.com/search?sort=pubdate&page_no={}&page_count=50&year_from=1996&year_to=2024&q=biomaterials&view=default"

    def start_requests(self):
        for page_no in range(218, 219):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url.format(page_no), cb_kwargs={"page_no": page_no, "index": 0})

    def parse(self, response, page_no, index):
        self.log(f"Scraping page number : {page_no}", logging.INFO)
        article_hrefs = response.xpath("//a[@class='title-link']/@href").getall()
        for href in article_hrefs:
            yield response.follow(url=href, callback=self.parse_page)

        if index < 50//15:     # 1 page with 15 articles plus 3 others = 50 items in total
            index += 1
            headers = {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "Referer": self.base_url.format(page_no),
                "USER_AGENT": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
            }
            yield scrapy.Request(url='https://www.mdpi.com/search/set/default/pagination', headers=headers, cb_kwargs={"page_no": page_no, "index": index}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        self.log(f"Scraping article: {response.url}", logging.INFO)

        title = response.xpath("//h1[contains(@class,'title')]//text()").getall()
        title = "".join(i.strip() for i in title)
        authors = response.xpath("//a[@class='profile-card-drop']//text()").getall()
        authors = [i.strip() for i in authors]
        email_href = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'email')]/@href").get(default="")
        email = decode_email_protection(email_href)

        yield {
            "Title": title,
            "Link": response.url,
            "Authors": authors,
            "Email": email
        }
```

Comment: there's a problem with your code, the page contain 50 article but it returns only 15 article .
i thought the problem in the for loop for the pagination so i edit the code to make it use the next page element, but still the same problem. 
do you know the reason ?

Comment: @mohamedagnaby you're absolutely right. See the updated code, I tested it on the given page and got 49 items and it matches the amount in the browser. I added an XML request to handle the item loading in the page.

Comment: i opened scrapy shell and did the following
>>> article_hrefs = response.xpath("//a[@class='title-link']/@href").getall()
>>> len(article_hrefs)
15
that's mean the article_hrefs doesn't get all the articles in the page.
i tried your code again and the weird thing it worked on the first page only i don't know why .
thanks for helping me, i really appreciate it

Comment: here's something i didn't notice, when i write the xpath in the browser it shows that i have 50 element but when i disabled javascript, i got only 15 element. i don't know what's the reason or what should i do

Comment: The articles are loaded dynamically with XHR requests, you can see this in the network tab in your browser's devtools. That's how I could recreate the request to get all the articles. Did you try the updated code? because I could get all the articles with it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace time.sleep(1) with something like:

> WebDriverWait(driver,
> 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
> 'your_xpath_here')))

Use cProfile to identify bottlenecks in your code. Optimize the slower parts of the script.

Use python's "multiprocessing" library to create parallel processes that scrape different pages at the same time.

Using and Scrapy and Selenium together is much more efficient. Scrapy can handle the initial page navigation, and then you can switch to Selenium for specific tasks like handling JavaScript-rendered content and so on...